# Problem with handling row selection with RxCocoa

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am studying RxCocoa for UITableView now. Everything works fine with presenting cells but when I add a closure to handle row selection a delay appears. I mean when I tap first row nothing happens, when I tap second row closure shows the reaction I expected for the first row, the third - for the second, etc...
Please have a look at my code and help me fix the problem.

```
import RxCocoa
import RxRelay
import RxSwift
import UIKit

final class ListViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    private var todos = BehaviorRelay<[String]>(value: ["Clean the apt", "Learn to code", "Call mom", "Do the workout", "Call customers"])
    let bag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "RxTodoList"
        tableView.dataSource = nil
        tableView.delegate = nil
        
        todos
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { (tableView, row, element) in
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodoCell")!
                cell.textLabel?.text = "\(element)"
                return cell
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
        
        tableView.rx
            .modelDeselected(String.self)
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] todo in
                print(todo)
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `modelDeselected` instead of `modelSelected`.

Also, you should never have a Subject, Relay, or Observable as a `var` they should always be `let`s. So `var todos = BehaviorRelay`... should be `let todos = BehaviorRelay`...

Lastly:

> The usage of subjects [and relays] should largely remain in the realms of samples and testing. Subjects are a great way to get started with Rx. They reduce the learning curve for new developers, however they pose several concerns...

-- ([IntroToRx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#CreationOfObservables))

Comment: Oh! Sure! So inaccurate of me! Thank you a lot!=)